# Progress bar doesn't function well

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, loading

I have an app that reads the smart cards and take a little bit long time
so I need to show a progress bar. However, I followed some tutorials it didn't work for me. The problem is,as seen in the picture, the progress bar remains at the same point even after filling the fields with the data.

[image: The Progress bar image]

These are my codes, as shown within them, I want the progress bar to be completed when data displayed equals to true, and then hide it along with the "Pleas Wait !!!" label.

```
public void DataDisplayed()
        {
            //bool displayedData = false;

            int t;
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 200;

            if (IDNumbertxt.Text != "" || FullNametxt.Text != "")
            {
                displayedData = true;
            }
            else
            {
                displayedData = false;
            }

            if (displayedData == false)
            {


                for (t = 0; t <= 100; t++)
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = t;

                }
            }
            else if (displayedData == true)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = 200;
                waitlbl.Hide();
                progressBar1.Hide();
            }
```

Pleas, anyone could help ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
for (t = 0; t <= 200; t++)
{
    progressBar1.Value = t;
}
```

because your for loop stop at 100 which is the middle value of your progress bar

**UPDATE**

```
if (displayedData == false)
{

    for (t = 0; t <= 100; t++)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = t;

    }
}
else
{
     progressBar1.Value = 200;
     waitlbl.Hide();
     progressBar1.Hide();
}
```

if you are using boolean you don't need to use an else if statement because boolean have only two answer it's either True or False

Also because your `progressBar1.Hide();` was inside your else condition the progress bar will hide almost instantly after the progress bar value change to 200

Comment: yes I know, but this statement is when the data displayed is false. the other statement is when the data displayed is true, and within it, I set the progress bat to 200. Thanks